# iOS app crashes on launch after 1 week

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, crash

I have successfully installed a few apps, written in pure swift, directly to my iPhone from Xcode. They work properly, except after ~1-2 weeks they crash on launch. See the below crash logs - can anyone help?

My iPhone 6 is running iOS 9.3.2 and I run Xcode 7.3.1

---

Aug 30 15:51:09 Andys-iPhone SpringBoard[2509] :  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName]
Aug 30 15:51:09 Andys-iPhone SpringBoard[2509] :  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName]
Aug 30 15:51:09 Andys-iPhone securityd[88] :  secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored taskRef found
Aug 30 15:51:09 Andys-iPhone securityd[88] :  secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored taskRef found
Aug 30 15:51:09 Andys-iPhone amfid[2396] :  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName]
Aug 30 15:51:09 Andys-iPhone amfid[2396] : /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/5F7C8A61-72B5-45F9-AB9D-01D0A82E3930/prioritize.app/prioritize not valid: 0xe8008015: A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found.
Aug 30 15:51:09 Andys-iPhone assertiond[67] : Unable to obtain a task name port right for pid 2726: (os/kern) failure (5)
Aug 30 15:51:09 Andys-iPhone SpringBoard[2509] : Unable to register for exec notifications: No such process
Aug 30 15:51:09 Andys-iPhone SpringBoard[2509] : Unable to obtain a task name port right for pid 2726: (os/kern) failure (5)
Aug 30 15:51:09 Andys-iPhone SpringBoard[2509] : Unable to obtain a task name port right for 
Aug 30 15:51:09 Andys-iPhone SpringBoard[2509] : Application 'UIKitApplication:keiretsuv.LPPA[0x3d2f]' exited abnormally via signal.
Aug 30 15:51:09 Andys-iPhone com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:keiretsuv.LPPA[0x3d2f][2726]) : Service exited due to signal: Killed: 9
Aug 30 15:51:09 Andys-iPhone SpringBoard[2509] : Application '(null)' exited for an unknown reason.
Aug 30 15:51:10 Andys-iPhone searchd[1105] : ====^^^^ DuetExpert missing data, count -> people:8 applicationDeepLinks:0 applications:8 requests:187 missingAllDataRequests:0
Aug 30 15:51:15 Andys-iPhone timed[2007] : (Note ) CoreTime: Want active time in 14.63min. Need active time in 8237.09min. Remaining retry interval: 0.000000min.
Aug 30 15:51:15 Andys-iPhone UserEventAgent[26] : validateAndAddDefaults(com.apple.timed): End Time (inf) > now (494283075.8) + BACKGROUND_TASK_AGENT_JOB_WINDOW_MAX_TIME_FROM_NOW_SEC (3024000.0) + BACKGROUND_TASK_AGENT_JOB_TIME_ERROR_MARGIN (300.0)
Aug 30 15:51:15 Andys-iPhone timed[2007] : (Error) CoreTime: Error requesting proactive time check job
Aug 30 15:51:16 Andys-iPhone timed[2007] : (Note ) CoreTime: Want active time in 14.74min. Need active time in 8244.19min. Remaining retry interval: 0.000000min.
Aug 30 15:51:16 Andys-iPhone UserEventAgent[26] : validateAndAddDefaults(com.apple.timed): End Time (inf) > now (494283076.9) + BACKGROUND_TASK_AGENT_JOB_WINDOW_MAX_TIME_FROM_NOW_SEC (3024000.0) + BACKGROUND_TASK_AGENT_JOB_TIME_ERROR_MARGIN (300.0)
Aug 30 15:51:16 Andys-iPhone timed[2007] : (Error) CoreTime: Error requesting proactive time check job
Aug 30 15:51:17 Andys-iPhone timed[2007] : (Note ) CoreTime: Want active time in 14.86min. Need active time in 8251.19min. Remaining retry interval: 0.000000min.
Aug 30 15:51:18 Andys-iPhone UserEventAgent[26] : validateAndAddDefaults(com.apple.timed): End Time (inf) > now (494283078.0) + BACKGROUND_TASK_AGENT_JOB_WINDOW_MAX_TIME_FROM_NOW_SEC (3024000.0) + BACKGROUND_TASK_AGENT_JOB_TIME_ERROR_MARGIN (300.0)
Aug 30 15:51:18 Andys-iPhone timed[2007] : (Error) CoreTime: Error requesting proactive time check job
Aug 30 15:51:19 Andys-iPhone timed[2007] : (Note ) CoreTime: Want active time in 14.97min. Need active time in 8258.09min. Remaining retry interval: 0.000000min.
Aug 30 15:51:19 Andys-iPhone UserEventAgent[26] : validateAndAddDefaults(com.apple.timed): End Time (inf) > now (494283079.1) + BACKGROUND_TASK_AGENT_JOB_WINDOW_MAX_TIME_FROM_NOW_SEC (3024000.0) + BACKGROUND_TASK_AGENT_JOB_TIME_ERROR_MARGIN (300.0)
Aug 30 15:51:19 Andys-iPhone timed[2007] : (Error) CoreTime: Error requesting proactive time check job

Comment: That's normal.  If you don't have a paid developer account the app expires after a week and you have to install it again from Xcode.

Comment: Thanks so much - I'm an idiot and was using my "Personal Team" instead of my apple developer team to sign the app. Appreciate it!